# Library's style attributes have no values even though they are explicitly set

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-styles, android-library

I made a library with a custom view that inflates a layout when created. Views in the layout are styled with `style="?attr/labelStyle"` or any other attribute.

The attribute is declared the library's `attrs.xml`:

```
<attr name="myViewStyle" format="reference"/>

<declare-styleable name="MyView">
    <attr name="labelStyle" format="reference|color"/>
</declare-styleable>
```

I have set a default value to this attribute in the library's `styles.xml`:

```
<style name="MyViewStyle">
    <item name="labelStyle">@style/LabelStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="LabelStyle">
    <item name="android:textColor">?android:attr/textColorPrimary</item>
    <item name="...">...</item>
</style>
```

And finally in the library's `themes.xml`:

```
<style name="MyViewStyleLight" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="myViewStyle">@style/MyViewStyle</item>
</style>
```

Now this was the library's default styles, but it is overridden in the main project `styles.xml`

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="myViewStyle">@style/MyViewStyleCustom</item>
</style>

<style name="MyViewStyleCustom" parent="MyViewStyleLight">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/gray</item>
    <item name="...">...</item>
</style>
```

The custom view code:

```
public MyView(Context context) {
    this(context, null, R.attr.myViewStyle, 0);
}

public MyView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, R.attr.myViewStyle, 0);
}

public MyView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    this(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, 0);
}

public MyView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
    super(createThemeWrapper(context, R.attr.myViewStyle, R.style.MyViewStyleLight),
            attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    initLayout();
}

private static Context createThemeWrapper(Context context, int styleAttr, int defaultStyle) {
    final TypedArray ta = context.obtainStyledAttributes(new int[]{styleAttr});
    int style = ta.getResourceId(0, defaultStyle);
    ta.recycle();
    return new ContextThemeWrapper(context, style);
}

private void initLayout() {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
    inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_view, this);
    ...
}
```

I explain about the ContextThemeWrapper below. Now the app crashes on the line where the layout gets inflated. Here's the important part of the crash log:

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class com.example.MyView
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
      [...]
    Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Failed to resolve attribute at index 13: TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x7f030057 a=-1}
      at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:867)
      [...]
```

The layout inflater can't find the attribute's value. When I tried to get the attribute by code, it returns nothing. The attribute actually exists, only it has no value set to it even though I have clearly set one.

How exactly I am supposed to style my library? I am almost certain that I did every thing the same as the [SublimePicker library](https://github.com/vikramkakkar/SublimePicker) but it just won't work. There's a little difference in the part with the ContextThemeWrapper, but it probably isn't the problem. I feel like I forgot a tiny thing somewhere that makes the attribute have no value, something is not connected, I don't know.

I know this is a very long question, but it cannot be more concise, I simplified everything as much as I could. I changed most of the information that was in the previous version of my question, making it completely different. The two answers are not relevant at all now, not that they ever were. The bounty was automatically rewarded.

If that could help someone I can add a download to my actual project, but as I said this simplified example has the exact same form as my project.

Comment: You say you've set a value to that attribute in your library and in your activity, but I see only one `<style>` definition in your question. Is that exact code duplicated in both places? Further, you say that you try to inflate the layout from the library; how exactly are you doing that? I have a guess as to what the problem is, but I'd rather not just post an answer without knowing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This answer is based on what I understand from your question and conversation between you and Vinayak B. If I misinterpret ,Please correct me.

there is difference in style.xml in both place app as well as lib. addition I have removed theme.xml as well as changes in constructor of MyView.java for default style

I have changed following things

- overridden in the main project styles.xml

  ```
  <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
      <item name="myViewStyle">@style/MyViewStyleCustom</item>
  </style>

  <style name="MyViewStyleCustom" parent="MyViewStyle">
      <item name="labelStyle">@style/LabelStyle123</item>
  </style>

  <style name="LabelStyle123">
      <item name="android:textColor">#f00</item>
  </style>
  ```
- lib styles.xml

  ```
  <resources>
      <style name="MyViewStyle">
          <item name="labelStyle">@style/LabelStyle</item>
          <item name="TextStyle">@style/textStyle</item>
      </style>

      <style name="LabelStyle">
          <item name="android:textColor">#00f</item>
      </style>

      <style name="textStyle">
          <item name="android:textColor">#009</item>
      </style>
  </resources>
  ```
- MyView.java - changed constructor of and set default MyViewStyle if no any attribute come from application.

  ```
  public MyView(Context context) {
      this(context, null, R.attr.myViewStyle,  R.style.MyViewStyle);
  }

  public MyView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
      this(context, attrs, R.attr.myViewStyle,  R.style.MyViewStyle);
  }

  public MyView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
      this(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, R.style.MyViewStyle);
  }

  public MyView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
      super(createThemeWrapper(context, defStyleAttr,defStyleRes), attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
      initLayout();
  }

  private static Context createThemeWrapper(Context context, int styleAttr, int defaultStyle) {
      final TypedArray ta = context.obtainStyledAttributes(new int[]{styleAttr});
      int style1 = ta.getResourceId(0, defaultStyle);
      ta.recycle();
      return new ContextThemeWrapper(context, style1);
  }
  ```

so either it will take default labelStyle if it is not overridden in main activity style or overridden labelStyle

Comment: How is that different from what I'm doing already? You copy-pasted my code to the answer!

Comment: there is difference in style.xml in both place app as well as lib.
addition I have removed theme.xml
as well as changes in constructor of MyView.java for default style

Comment: Sorry, I spoke too fast, it works thanks A LOT! The issue was probably with the constructors using 0 as the default style attribute... I must've spent 10 hours trying to figure this out, thank you. If you edit your answer I can change the downvote.

Answer (score 3):

This answer is based on what I  understand from your question. If I misinterpret
,Please correct me.

First of all `myTextColor` is an attribute name in your library. not a attribute value. You supposed to give a value for `myTextColor` when ever you using this library. Otherwise there may occur `'InflateException'` . You can avoid this by following way.

```
<YourCustomeView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:myTextColor="#000"/>
```

1. Set `myTextColor` value directly when you use outside the library.

> OR

2. In your library where you using this `myTextColor` attribute, check if this attribute have value or not. If it doesn't have any value then use a default value for `myTextColor`

   ```
    private void init(@Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
                TypedArray ta = getContext().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, 
                                R.styleable.MyLibrary);
           boolean hasRawRes = ta.hasValue(R.styleable.myTextColor);
           if(hasRawRes){
             // Use `myTextColor` attr here
           }else{
             // use default color
           }
   ```

   }

> UPDATE ANSWER

This answer for the updated question

First of all you are trying to fetch a `attr` value from your library  to your project using `?attr/` .Which does not going to work. because

Your project using `Theme.AppCompat`  theme as (I'm guessing) parent theme for your Activities. When you use `?attr` inside that activity, you can only fetch attribute values of `Theme.AppCompat`. But you are trying to fetch `?attr/labelStyle` which is not a attribute of `Theme.AppCompat` rather than it's your library attribute. That's why you are getting that crash. If you want to use any style from your library to your project you can use `@style` tag

For example

```
 style="@style/labelStyle"
```

If it's not what you are looking for ,Please kindly share your source code.So I can understand more on this problem.

Comment: No, I want to create a color attribute, the same way `?attr/colorPrimary` is. [This article](https://mobikul.com/create-custom-attributes-reference-color-style-xml-android/) explains what I'm trying to do but it dopesn't seem to work in a library

Comment: In that case 2nd option will help you. Please  try that. anyway if you want to use '?attr/myTextColor' in your project, you have to set a value in your project's  style.xml.

Comment: @VinayakB seems to be write, and its also how SublimePicker library you quoted works. I think your missunderstood the purpose of custom style attribute definition, its not for global library usage, but for customView definition. In your case, you just have to define a default text color resource in your library, and override it in your app, it should do the work.

Comment: Yes well I am changing my Dialog fragments to custom views instead like in the Sublime picker, it might help me.

Comment: @VinayakB I'm a bit late, but I just tested the 2nd option and it doesn't have a value...

Comment: yes. You have to add myTextColor to your app style . otherwise you won't get a value

Comment: @VinayakB Do you have any other solution?

Answer (score 0):

Here's my guess: I suspect that, despite `<style>` tag you posted above, the attribute is actually not defined when inflating from your library, probably because your library project is using a `Context` with a "bad" theme when inflating the dialog.

The `?attr` syntax means that the value for the variable is read from the context's *theme*, not from a view's style or attributes. From a Google dev blog post:

> This ?attr/ format allows you to pull any attribute out of your theme, making it easy to consolidate your theming into a single place and avoid finding/replacing across many files.

So you have to make sure that you either handle the case where the inflating context's theme does not define this attribute, or only ever inflate this dialog with a theme that defines the attribute.